# Cannot connect with remote dekstop to my win8.1 PRO desktop

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, windows-8.1, remote-desktop

I have a desktop computer running Windows 8.1, I upgraded it from the regular version to the PRO version  so I can use the Remote Desktop feature (as host). But no matter what I can't connect to it from my laptop running Windows 7 Home Premium edition. Even when I connect both to the same local network at my home I still can't connect. I tried to use the computer's name and it's internal IP address (when accessing it from the same local network of course) but it always throws the same error. When I try to connect from outside the local network I use the public IP address and I forwarded the needed ports, but no matter what I get the same error.

The error:

[image]

P.S

I did choose "Allow computers to connect to this computer" in the Remote Settings.

**EDIT:**

After intensive reading, I found out that the `TermService` is the main service behind the Remote Desktop. Looking at my Win8.1 Pro system, I saw that this service failed to start, when atteping to start it manually I get this:

[image]

Also, notice the description of the service...

I'm currently trying to find a fix for that hoping it will resolve my intial issue.
Can it be the cause for the problem? If it is, how can I fix that?

Comment: Error 0xc1 maps to ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT - which means that something is wrong with TermService. Did you update from 32bit to 64 bit by any chance?

Comment: Also, you might want to take a look in ''eventvwr.exe'' -> under Applications and Services Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> TerminalServices* and Remote* to see if any logs show up with details about the failure to start.

Comment: @cdavid I had the 64bit version from the beginning, I've never installed a 32bit copy in this computer. And I looked around in the log files generated by the Window's System File Checker Tool and found out that `termsrv.dll` located at `C:/Windows/System32` is corrupted and it was unable to fix it. Is there any way I can get a wroking copy of this file?

Comment: I would suggest getting it from another good, running computer with the same OS / arch installed. Make sure on the other computer you disable the service first (otherwise it will not let you copy), copy the file, reenable the service.

Comment: @cdavid  It won't let me replace it because of owner permissions or seomthing

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you're not authorised to connect to your Win8.1 PC.

In addition to checking the **Allow computers to connect to this computer**, you also have to choose which users are allowed to connect to it.

In your Windows 8.1 computer:

[image]

Under **Select Users>Remote Desktop Users** to add a user. For example, if I wanted to connect to my Win8.1 Pro from Win7, and I had a Microsoft account abcd@hotmail.com user on my Win8.1 computer, I would click  **Add** and type in abcd@hotmail.com. So when I want to connect to Win8.1 from Win7, I would use the credentials (abcd email + password) to connect:

---

**EDIT**

It seems that Microsoft has a solution for your exact same situation [here](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/555382). Try following the steps there.

Also see [here](http://batcmd.com/windows/8/services/termservice/) too.

Comment: It does not allow me to connect with a username like that (Maybe because I'm currently trying to connect from outside of my local network?) But anyway, shouldn't I be able to connect with an IP and  be prompt with entering credentials?

Comment: I updated my question with more information, maybe you'll have an idea on how to solve this from there?